# Running sbt test suite twice causes jdbc Driver not found error

Tags: java, scala, sqlite, jdbc, sbt

The first time I run a test suite that depends on a jdbc sql lite driver the test suite passes. If I attempt to run the test suite again, the test fails citing not finding a appropriate driver for the database. Here is the console session:

```
> > test-only *EclairTest*
15:56:27.386 TKD [EclairTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] ERROR a.h.i.engine.client.PoolMasterActor - connection pool for PoolGateway(hcps = HostConnectionPoolSetup(localhost,18332,ConnectionPoolSetup(ConnectionPoolSettings(4,0,5,32,1,30 seconds,ClientConnectionSettings(Some(User-Agent: akka-http/10.1.1),10 seconds,1 minute,512,None,WebSocketSettings(<function0>,ping,Duration.Inf,<function0>),List(),ParserSettings(2048,16,64,64,8192,64,8388608,256,1048576,Strict,RFC6265,true,Full,Error,Map(If-Range -> 0, If-Modified-Since -> 0, If-Unmodified-Since -> 0, default -> 12, Content-MD5 -> 0, Date -> 0, If-Match -> 0, If-None-Match -> 0, User-Agent -> 32),false,true,<function1>,<function1>,<function2>),None,TCPTransport),New,1 second),akka.http.scaladsl.HttpConnectionContext$@5fb80e0c,akka.event.MarkerLoggingAdapter@7da2ada2))) has shut down unexpectedly
[ERROR] [06/13/2018 15:56:27.404] [EclairTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(EclairTest)] exception while executing timer task
[info] EclairTest:
[info] EclairTest
[info] - should connect to a running eclair instance
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 3 seconds, 2 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
[info] Passed: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 1
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed Jun 13, 2018 3:56:27 PM

> test-only *EclairTest*
[info] EclairTest:
[info] com.suredbits.api.ln.EclairTest *** ABORTED ***
[info]   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/home/chris/.eclair/regtest/eclair.sqlite
[info]   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
[info]   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
[info]   at fr.acinq.eclair.NodeParams$.makeNodeParams(NodeParams.scala:136)
[info]   at fr.acinq.eclair.Setup.<init>(Setup.scala:71)
[info]   at com.suredbits.api.ln.EclairTest.<init>(EclairTest.scala:20)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[info]   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[info]   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[info]   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[info]   ...
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 589 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 1
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] *** 1 SUITE ABORTED ***
[error] Error: Total 1, Failed 0, Errors 1, Passed 0
[error] Error during tests:
[error]         com.suredbits.api.ln.EclairTest
[error] (api/test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 13, 2018 3:56:31 PM
```

This seems to be pretty bizzare to me. What do you think could be causing this issue? If I shutdown sbt and restart, I see the same behavior.

---

The test looks like this:

```
class EclairTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("EclairTest")) with FlatSpecLike with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatcher

  behavior of "EclairTest"

  //assumes eclair is running
  val datadir = new File("/home/chris/.eclair")
  val setup = new Setup(
    datadir = datadir,
    actorSystem = system
  )
  val params = setup.nodeParams
  val kitF: Future[Kit] = setup.bootstrap

  it should "connect to a running eclair instance" in {
    val balance: Future[fr.acinq.bitcoin.Satoshi] = kitF.flatMap(_.wallet.getBalance)
    balance.map(b => assert(b.toLong >= 0))
  }

  override def afterAll: Unit = {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }
}
```

and the dependency is bundled into another dependency, but i also included sqlite explicitly with

```
val hikari = ("com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % V.slickV).exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-api")
val slick = "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % V.slickV withSources() withJavadoc()
val dbcp = "commons-dbcp" % "commons-dbcp" % "1.4"
val postgresql = "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1210"
val sqlite = "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % V.sqliteV

lazy val api = project
      .in(file("."))
      .enablePlugins()
      .settings(
        mainClass := Some("com.suredbits.api.Main"), 
        fork in test := true,
        resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),  
        resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal,
        libraryDependencies ++= Deps.api
      )
```

---

The open source project and the pom.xml file of the open source project is defined here: https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair/blob/master/eclair-core/pom.xml#L175-L179

Comment: please update your sbt dependencies and how your test setup look like for sqlite??

Comment: This is most likely an issue with running tests in the same _JVM_ instance as _SBT_, causing cumulative problems on second+ test runs. You can likely fix this by adding `fork in test := true` to your _SBT_ build file...

Comment: @MikeAllen This did not work.

Comment: Can you post relevant portions of your build file?

Comment: @MikeAllen I've added more to the OP

Comment: There's still not enough there for me to help you. I strongly suspect that the problem is with the setup.bootstrap statement, since its executing in the same JVM each time, and not giving up it's resources. Can you show your build file, showing everything related to testing. (Don't need publishing stuff, signing keys, etc. but keep the structure.) What SBT plugins are you using?

Comment: BTW, I think it's supposed to be `fork in Test := true`, with a capital T. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MikeAllen After i modified the key, you were right! So basically the underlying library needs to be provide a clean shutdown for database connections in `Kit`?

Comment: Correct. Ideally, tests should free resources they've claimed. In your case, the Eclair library seems to assume that it's going to be run in a fresh JVM each time, and so there's no apparent way to clean up at the end of your test. I don't think it's an _Akka TestKit_ issue.

Comment: If you write up an answer summarizing that I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the `Setup.bootstrap` method, which claims the database in the *Eclair* library, relies upon the *JVM* exiting to clean-up after it, and doesn't appear to provide a mechanism for allowing you do so manually at the end of your test. (If there is such a mechanism, using that would do the trick too.)

By default, tests run in the same *JVM* that the *SBT* build instance runs in, so the resources claimed in the first run of the test are still present when you run the test a second time. Except that, on the second and subsequent runs, they're unable to claim the database resources because they're already claimed.

By adding:

```scala
fork in Test := true
```

to your *SBT* build, you're forcing each test instance to run in its own *JVM* instance, so it can start afresh each time.